# How to pretty format the printing of SQL queries in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, formatting

I'm using SQLAlchemy to generate PL/SQL on the fly using `compile` and setting the `dialect` and `compile_kwargs` arguments (e.g., using `str(ins.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect(), compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))`). This works fine, except the output is not formatted in the most pretty SQL statement ever.

For example, one of my outputs looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (a, b, c) SELECT my_table2.d, bar.e, bar.f
FROM my_table2 JOIN (SELECT my_table3.e AS e, max(my_table3.f) AS f, count(my_table3.g) AS g
FROM my_table3
WHERE my_table3.h = 'foo' GROUP BY my_table3.e
HAVING count(my_table3.g) = 1) bar ON my_table2.g = bar.g
```

Instead, I would want this to print out like the following:

```
INSERT INTO my _table (a, b c)
SELECT my_table2.d, bar.e, bar.f
FROM my_table2 JOIN (
    SELECT my_table3.e, max(my_table3.f), count(my_table3.g)
    FROM my_table3
    WHERE my_table3.h = 'foo'
    GROUP BY my_table3.e
    HAVING count(my_table3.g) = 1
) bar ON my_table2.g = bar.g
```

How can I get SQLAlchemy to pretty print the SQL statements?

---

To replicate:

```
from sqlalchemy import table, column, String, Numeric, func, select
from sqlalchemy.dialects import oracle
my_table = table('my_table', column('a', String), column('b', String), column('c', String))
my_table2 = table('my_table2', column('d', String), column('g', String))
my_table3 = table('my_table3', column('d', String), column('e', String), column('f', Numeric), column('g', String), column('h', String))

inner_sel = select([my_table3.c.e, func.max(my_table3.c.f).label('f'), func.count(my_table3.c.g).label('g')]).where(my_table3.c.h=='foo').group_by(my_table3.c.e).having(func.count(my_table3.c.g)==1).alias('bar')


outer_sel = select([my_table2.c.d, inner_sel.c.e, inner_sel.c.f]).select_from(my_table2.join(inner_sel, my_table2.c.g==inner_sel.c.g))

ins = my_table.insert().from_select([my_table.c.a, my_table.c.b, my_table.c.c], outer_sel)

print ins.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect(), compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True})
```

Comment: I don't think that's supported out of the box. Try [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse).

Comment: It's still trying to do something, as it seems: it's not all on 1 line, but has some breaks before SQL keywords... Well, I'm also searching for something free and smart for this task.

Comment: Related: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple of options to try:

- [Pygments](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygments-pprint-sql/0.1.0)
- [sqlparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse)
- [format-sql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/format-sql/)

Comment: Note that out of these three, only `sqlparse` is actively maintained.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the sqlparse package and `sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')`. IT should do what you want.

Comment: Great example. Thanks.

Comment: imho shandy-sqlfmt (see http://sqlfmt.com/) is much faster and prettier.  equivalent api command is `format_string(sql, Mode())`

Answer (score 19):

The project [`sqlparse`](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse) is mature (more than 10 years) and is still very active. `sqlparse` aims at parsing, splitting and formatting SQL statements.

The following example uses `sqlparse` to pretty formats SQL files:

```py
import argparse
import sqlparse

# Parse command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="pretty_print_sql")
parser.add_argument("file", type=argparse.FileType("r"), nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Pretty print input files
for file in args.file:
    print(sqlparse.format(file.read(), reindent=True, keyword_case='upper'))
```

To install `sqlparse` using `pip` for personal usage:

```
python3 -m pip install sqlparse --user --upgrade
```

To install `sqlparse` using `pipenv` (within a project):

```
python3 -m pipenv install sqlparse
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this monkey patch:

`pip install sqlparse`

```
### monkeypatching SQL'Alchemy for pretty SQL query printing (((
from sqlalchemy.log import InstanceLogger


def pretty_log(self, level, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.logger.manager.disable >= level:
        return

    selected_level = self._echo_map[self.echo]
    if selected_level == logging.NOTSET:
        selected_level = self.logger.getEffectiveLevel()

    if level >= selected_level:

        import sqlparse
        ### HERE IT IS ###
        msg = sqlparse.format(msg, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')

        self.logger._log(level, '\n'+msg, args, **kwargs)

InstanceLogger.log = pretty_log
### )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following both [v_retoux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335158/how-to-pretty-format-the-printing-of-sql-queries-in-sqlalchemy/44335609#44335609) and  [oHo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636162/286807)'s examples, I created [an easy-to-deploy script on GitHub](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/sqlpp) that uses [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse). It handles one or more SQL files and has a clean output that can be piped for single files.

Here is the source:

```
import argparse, sqlparse, re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="sqlpp")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", "-v", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("file", type=argparse.FileType("r"), nargs="+")

args = parser.parse_args()

def prepend(s, s2): return s2 + re.sub('\n', '\n'+s2, s)

# Pretty print input files
n=len(args.file)
for i, file in enumerate(args.file):
    sIn = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    file.close()
    sOut = sqlparse.format(sIn, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')
    if args.verbose or n > 1:
        print("File{0}:\n    {1}\n{2}\nFormatted SQL:\n{3}\n".format(
             (' ' + str(i+1) if n > 1 else '')
            ,file.name
            ,("\nOriginal SQL:\n{}\n".format(prepend(sIn, "    "))
                    if args.verbose else "")
            ,prepend(sOut, "    ")
        ))
    else:
        print(sOut)
```

Comment: Yea, I was on the fence on whether to add  the code. I'll put in the main body of logic now.

Comment: There isn't anyone with the name "olibre" here. Does it refer to Alan's or oHo'a answer?

Comment: Noted. Must have been oHo's. I'll update my answer.