# Format SQL in a string (in python or any language)

Tags: python, sql, formatting

Is there a cli tool that can be used to format SQL code inside strings in a given .py file? Example:

```
import foo

query = """SELECT please, format, me    

FROM    i-am-an-unformatted-query

"""

some_client.query(query)
```

could for example yield

```
import foo

query = """
SELECT
    please,
    format,
    me    
FROM i-am-an-unformatted-query"""

some_client.query(query)
```

ie, formatting would only occur inside the query string.

Does such a tool exist? The once I've looked at only format standalone files. I would prefer not having discussions about SQL formatting with my colleagues but align around a tool, much like we do with for example `black` for python formatting.

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44335609/687896

Comment: Not really, no. I want to point a tool to a file, for example a python file. Then i want to format any string inside that python file that looks like a sql query, and write the file back.

Answer (score 0):

According to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44335609/687896, in Python you can use package `sqlparse`:

```py
>>> import sqlparse
>>> sql = """SELECT please, format, me    

FROM    i-am-an-unformatted-query

"""

>>> sql_formatted = sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')
>>> print(sql_formatted)
SELECT please,
       format,
       me
FROM i-am-an-unformatted-query
```

Comment: Yes, for formatting a given string, that's fine. But I want to point the tool to a python (or other) file that contain both SQL and _other code_, the latter should remain untouched.

Answer (score -1):

I mean I probably didn't get your question right but, if you're referring to formatting the query i.e : changing it based upon a request or variable you could simply use:

```
print( """
SELECT {},
   format, me    
FROM i-am-an-unformatted-query""",format(please))
```

and the print could be placed in a function that takes the please as an argument.

Comment: Yes, for formatting a given string, that's fine. But I want to point the tool to a python (or other) file that contain both SQL and other code, the latter should remain untouched.